# How do I add a 2ga neutral to ITE EQ Load Center?

Tags: electrical

[image][image]

I need to attach a 2 gauge neutral wire to my ITE EQ main panel neutral bar to run to a new sub panel.  But, the neutral bar will not accept/fit a 2 ga wire. So, I assume I need to add a neutral lug to the bar.  But, by adding a lug it seems like the lug screw will contact the panel cover when that is put back on.  Is there a particular lug to use on an ITE EQ panel that will work in this situation? Brand? Model? Any suggestions?

[image: ITE EQ Load Center][2]]

Comment: Could you add a picture of the panel label? Also, have you done the neutral math to validate that you need a 2ga neutral? The neutral can sometimes be sized down, maybe all the way down to #6 in this case.

Comment: Yes, we'll need a photo of the label on the inside of the door as that'll tell us what lugs your panel accepts

Comment: Look carefully at the panel label for accessory part numbers. Technically only accessories on the label are acceptable, but considering the panel is out  of production if an ECCS1 or an LK70ANCP line up I doubt an inspector would object.

Comment: As for potentially hitting the cover - you appear to have the "high/low" neutral bars stacked arrangement, so you could move some wires to put the new lug on the lower rail.

Comment: And regarding that, note the panel labeling may allow 2 or 3 grounds to share a screw, but only 1 neutral per screw.

Comment: ECCS1 or an LK70ANCP don't fit...the lug fits on the bar, but the screws are too small and threads don't hold .  Also...correction...ITE catalog number is EQ 20 mbb and the ITE collar strap part number b-2096.  Anyone know of a link to ask Seimens about a part that fits the neutral bar?

Comment: Also, bonding screw question.  The bonding screw between the ground and neutral bars on the left side.  It just spins.  Is it broken?  Is this safe? Can I install another screw on the opposite side between the neutral and ground bars on on the the right?

Comment: On the bonding screw, if you don't trust it (and I don't either)... just run a hard ground wire (or two!) from the neutral bar to the physical frame of the box.  Use bolt and nut, or if you prefer, you can drill the panel and tap it for #8-32 or #10-32 fine thread machine screw, and that is good enough for direct via-thread contact.  10-32 is the quasi-standard for junction box ground screws. Also some boxes have pre-tapped 8-32 holes intended for accessory ground bars, and that there is another option.